# PYTHON split ThreadPoolExecutor to multiple CPU Cores

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Hey I am pretty new to this community and I was wondering if this is possible?

For example I have a ThreadPoolExecutor with:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from threading import Semaphore

lock = Semaphore(1)

# Just a pseudocode example
profileTasks = ["TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4", ....]

def runTask(index, profile):
     lock.acquire()
     print(f"{index} with {profile}")
     lock.release()

runningLoop = True
while runningLoop:

    """
        Launch anyways with PoolExecutor
    """
    
    tasks = []
    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
        for index, profile in enumerate(profileTasks):

            tasks.append(
                executor.submit(
                    runTask, index, profile
                )
            )
    
    runningLoop = False
```

When I launch for instance more than 100 tasks the threads take so long to start from the executor, I want to split the workload so if I run 1000 tasks and I have a CPU with example 8 cores I want to split the 1000 tasks by 8 multiprocesses in which I run the thread pool executors.

I hope you understand what I mean, Threading in python is in general not petty smart cause it only uses 1 CPU core.

I tried counting the CPU cores and to execute it in a MultiProcessExecutor but it was a complete failure and froze my CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The mostly used Python implementation (from `python.org`, commonly referred to as `cpython` because it is written in C) *enforces* that only *one thread at a time* can be executing python bytecodes.
So using threads to speed up computationally intensive applications does not work with this implementation.

If you want to use multiple cores for running the same job, you have to use e.g. a `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. The latter is built on top of `multiprocessing`.

---

Based on your comments, if your task is to sent HTTP or other network traffic then a `ThreadPoolExecutor` might be more appropriate.

Because I/O (be it disk or network) in `cpython` does not suffer from the aforementioned restriction. In technical terms, the Global Interpreter Lock in `cpython` is released during I/O, giving other threads time to run.

However, network I/O has its own problems.

If you look at performance;

- the CPU running instructions and data from its cache is the fastest. (In order to keep this simple, I will not distinguish between bandwidth and latency here.)
- If the CPU has to get data or instructions from memory, that is much slower than from the cache.
- Disk I/O (especially HDD) is much slower than memory.
- Network I/O is generally much slower than disk.

For example, when writing data (from `/dev/zero` to a file on disk) I've observed speeds of ≈200 MB/s on a SATA 3 harddisk using ZFS.

When using `netcat` to blast files from one computer to the other over a gigabit point-to-point ethernet link with no other traffic (probably the best possible case for consumer equipment at this time), I get maximum ≈120 MB/s. When e.g. downloading a video from the internet, I might get in the order of ≈12 MB/s max.

If you want to use a 1000 simultaneous network queries, a couple of things can happen:

- You could saturate your internet connection. Instead of the tasks competing for CPU time, they are now competing for network bandwidth. This does not improve throughput nor latency.
- Your ISP might restrict throughput.
- If all the queries go to the same domain, you might trigger a denial of service attack warning and that domain's firewall will block or restrict your connections.

In short: running a 1000 queries at the same time from a single IP address is probably not a good idea.

Comment: yeah but the thing is its not possible to run 1k processes in a ProcessPoolExecutor, the CPU ramps up immediately and the computer freezes, Threads are not parallel but I want a parallel solution while having the option that the program will start up and not freeze the PC if you know what I mean.

Comment: When creating a `ProcessPoolExecutor` you should generally **not** set `max_workers` to much more than the amount of cores your CPU has. (Unless the workers are `sleep`-ing a significant amount of time.)  Because if you do e.g. set `max_workers=1000` on a 4--12 core CPU it will only lead to workers fighting over CPU time.

Comment: yes but how do I run then 1k tasks parallel under a CPU while using multi processing, the tasks are heavy in the real solution not just a print?

I am doing multiple requests and with threading the ThreadPoolExecutor takes more than 1 minute to launch 100 Threads.

Comment: You can't really do that on a single machine. If you start 1k tasks on a 4-core CPU, you will end up with 996 tasks waiting to be run and 4 tasks running. The process scheduler will ensure that every task gets a bit of CPU time now and then. Note that cou *can* create a large amount of `Futures`. But they will only be run N at a time, where N is the number of CPU's.   If you *really* need 1k parallel tasks, you should probably move to a cluster and use e.g. `mpi`.

Comment: You mention "requests". Does that mean network traffic? Because that completely changes the scenario.

Comment: Yes I want to sent requests, thank you for your quick responses.